# Finding a bijection

Tags: real-analysis

In the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem, suppose that $A = B =\mathbb{N}$ and that both the functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ are the doubling functiona $n \mapsto 2n$. Find the bijection $h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that the proof of the theorem produces.

From what I understand $a_1=1,a_2=2\dots$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(a_i)=2,4,6,8,\dots$

Then $b_1=2,b_2=4,b_3=6\dots$ so $g(b_j)=4,8,12,16,\dots$

So how do I derive a bijections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup, we do not encounter finite cycles in the construction, nor are there doubly-infinite strings. Instead, all such strings have a beginning at an odd number. If that odd number $a$ is in $A$, then the construction tells us to define $h(a)=f(a)$, $h(g(f(a)))=f(g(f(a)))$, etc. that is $h(2^{2k}a)=2^{2k+1}a$. If on the other hand that initial odd number $a$ is in $B$, the construction tells us to map $h(g(a))=a$, $h(g(f(g(a)))=f(g(a))$, etc., that is $h(2^{2k+1}a)=2^{2k}a$. In summary, given $n\in\mathbb N$, write it as $n=2^ma$ with $a$ odd and then set $$h(n)=\begin{cases}2n&\text{if $m$ is even}\\n/2&\text{if $m$ is odd}\end{cases}$$